# Is .withColumn and .agg calculated in parallel in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider for example

```
df.withColumn("customr_num", col("customr_num").cast("integer")).\
withColumn("customr_type", col("customr_type").cast("integer")).\
agg(myMax(sCollect_list("customr_num")).alias("myMaxCustomr_num"), \
    myMean(sCollect_list("customr_type")).alias("myMeanCustomr_type"), \
    myMean(sCollect_list("customr_num")).alias("myMeancustomr_num"),\
    sMin("customr_num").alias("min_customr_num")).show()
```

Are *.withColumn* and the list of functions inside *agg* (sMin, myMax, myMean, etc.) calculated in parallel by Spark, or in sequence ?

If sequential, how do we parallelize them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By essence, as long as you have more than one partition, operations are always parallelized in spark. If what you mean though is, are the `withColumn` operations going to be computed in one pass over the dataset, then the answer is also yes. In general, you can use the Spark UI to know more about the way things are computed.

Let's take an example that's very similar to your example.

```scala
spark.range(1000)
    .withColumn("test", 'id cast "double")
    .withColumn("test2", 'id + 10)
    .agg(sum('id), mean('test2), count('*))
    .show
```

And let's have a look at the UI.

[image]

`Range` corresponds to the creation of the data, then you have `project` (the two `withColumn` operations) and then the aggregation (`agg`) within each partition (we have 2 here). In a given partition, these things are done sequentially, but for all the partitions at the same time. Also, they are in the same stage (on blue box) which mean that they are all computed in one pass over the data.

Then there is a shuffle (`exchange`) which mean that data is exchanged over the network (the result of the aggregations per partition) and the final aggregation is performed (`HashAggregate`) and then sent to the driver (`collect`)

Comment: What I meant is : Consider your example, there are a couple of column operations : withColumn_test, withColumn_test2, agg_sum, agg_mean, agg_count. If I understand your answer correctly, we have (withColumn_test, withColumn_test2) in parallel, then after that's done, we have 3 operations (agg_sum, agg_mean, agg_count) in parallel. What I am afraid is (withColumn_test) -> (withColumn_tes2) -> (agg_sum,agg_mean, agg_count) or even worse, all sequential. I have some operations on all columns and afraid that they are not calculated in parallel.

Comment: In parallel is not the word I would use, but in your example and in mine as well, I can assure you that spark is not passing though the data several time. All the computations (withColumn and the partition wise aggs) are computed at the same time (i.e. during the same pass of the data).

Comment: Basically, as long as you use SparkSQL, if you can think of a reasonable optimization you would use to speed up your query, Spark probably performs it. To be sure, just check the UI. Do not hesitate if that's still unclear.

Comment: So what he is wanting to know is if the withColumns are happening in parallel within the partition or one after the other. You state sequentially, which is my understanding. Nuance is there may be less executors working than anticipated.

Comment: Maybe distributed is the word your'e looking for.

Comment: What purpose to show the diagrams? They do not aid in understanding the question. I assume you are correct but rereading your answer I don’t feel you have answered it in reality.